# Fiddler access nested json to modify

Tags: c#, arrays, json, fiddler

i somehow can´t reach the objects in a nested json. I easily can reach the element test, but how to reach this_month inside "stats"? this is my json:

```
{"test":"OK","stats":{"this_month":"1653","this_week":"1653"}}
```

this is my code inside the customrules.cs

```
        var oResponseBody = oSession.GetResponseBodyAsString();
        JSON.JSONParseResult oJSON = JSON.JsonDecode(oResponseBody) as JSON.JSONParseResult;
        Hashtable oObj = oJSON.JSONObject as Hashtable; 

        oObj["test"] = "changed";




         var modBytes = Fiddler.WebFormats.JSON.JsonEncode(oObj);

        // Convert json to bytes, storing the bytes in request body
        var mod = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(modBytes);
        oSession.ResponseBody = mod;
```

As soon as I want to acces this_month in "stats" with this:  `oObj["stats"]["this_month"] = "changed";` my fiddler get´s errors and crashes.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but looks like you may need to cast, ie: `((Hashtable)oObj["stats"])["this_month"] = "somevalue";`

Comment: it works like this, but after changes the value it crashes again. there is some looping with this method what causes to crash i guess